# gnu makefile filter a list of source files through a list of folders to ignore

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu

Lets say I have the following variables:

```
SOURCES = folder1/a.c folder1/b.c folder2/c.c folder3/d.c folder3/e.c
FILTERS = folder2 folder3
```

Now I want to set a variable that contains only `folder1/a.c folder1/b.c`. I have tried `$(filter-out folder2%,$(SOURCES))` and that does remove the unwatned folder2 items. So maybe I can somehow loop through the FILTERS in this way?

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use:

```
OUTPUT := $(filter-out $(addsuffix /%,$(FILTERS)),$(SOURCES))
```

`filter-out` can take multiple filters and applies them all.  I recommend you use `/%` instead of just `%` so you don't catch filenames that happen to start with the name of the directories.